# How to find and replace 6 digit numbers within HREF links from map of values across site files, ideally using SED/Python

Tags: python, html, regex, bash, sed

I need to create a BASH script, ideally using SED to find and replace value lists in `href` URL link constructs with HTML sit files, looking-up in a map (old to new values), that have a given URL construct. There are around 25K site files to look through, and the map has around 6,000 entries that I have to search through.

All old and new values have 6 digits.

The URL construct is:

**One value:**
`HREF=".*jsp\?.*N=[0-9]{1,}.*"`

**List of values:**
`HREF=".*\.jsp\?.*N=[0-9]{1,}+N=[0-9]{1,}+N=[0-9]{1,}...*"`

The list of values are delimited by `+` PLUS symbol, and the list can be `1` to `n` values in length.

I want to ignore a construct such as this:

`HREF=".*\.jsp\?.*N=0.*"`

IE the list is only `N=0`

Effectively I'm only interested in URL's that include one or more values that are in the file map, that are not prepended with `CHANGED` -- IE the list requires updating.

**PLEASE NOTE:** in the above construct examples: `.*` means any character that isn't a digit; I'm just interested in any 6 digit values in the list of values after `N=`; so I've trying to isolate the `N=` list from the rest of the URL construct, and it should be noted that this `N=` list can appear anywhere within this URL construct.

**Initially**, I want to create a script that will create a report of all links that fulfills the above criteria and that have a 6 digital OLD value that's in the map file, with its file path, to get an understanding of links impacted. EG:

```
Filename    link
filea.jsp   /jsp/search/results.jsp?N=204200+731&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=
filea.jsp   /jsp/search/BROWSE.jsp?Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&N=213890+217867+731&
fileb.jsp   /jsp/search/results.jsp?N=0+450+207827+213767&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=
```

**Lastly**, I'd like to find and replace all 6 digit numbers, within the URL construct lists, as outlined above, as efficiently as possible (I'd like it to be reasonably fast as there could be around 25K files, with 6K values to look up, with potentially multiple values in the list).

****PLEASE NOTE:**** There is an additional issue I have, when finding and replacing, is that an old value could have been assigned a new value, that's already been used, that may also have to be replaced.

E.G. If the map file is as below:

```
MAP-FILE.txt
OLD     NEW
214865  218494
214866  217854
214867  214868
214868  218633
...     ...
```

and there is a HREF link such as:

`/jsp/search/results.jsp?Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&Ntk=gensearch&N=0+450+214867+214868`

`214867` changes to `214868` - this would need to be prepended to flag that this value has been changed, and should not be replaced, otherwise what was `214867` would become `218633` as all `214868` would be changed to `218633`. Hope this makes sense - I would then need to run through file and remove all 6 digit numbers that had been marked with the prepended flag, such that link would become:

`/jsp/search/results.jsp?Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&Ntk=gensearch&N=0+450+214868CHANGED+218633CHANGED`

Unless there's a better way to manage these infile changes.

Could someone please help me on this, I'm note an expert with these kind of changes - so help would be massively appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: If I were you I would make a Python script and run it in Bash. I have not read all the text but it seams that there are too many conditions. I see at least two nested loops here. Why should I use some strange BASH command SED when I can easily code it in Python?

Comment: @keiv.fly Added a Python tag to my question. How would you look to implement in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I will write the outline for the code in some kind of pseudocode. And I don't remember Python well to quickly write the code in Python.

First find what type it is (if contains N=0 then type 3, if contains "+" then type 2, else type 1) and get a list of strings containing "N=..." by exploding (name of PHP function) by "+" sign.

The first loop is on links. The second loop is for each N= number. The third loop looks in map file and finds the replacing value. Load the data of the map file to a variable before all the loops. File reading is the slowest operation you have in programming.
You replace the value in the third loop, then implode (PHP function) the list of new strings to a new link when returning to a first loop.

Probably you have several files with the links then you need another loop for the files.

When dealing with repeated codes you nees a while loop until spare number found. And you need to save the numbers that are already used in a list.